# How to fix "Runtime error 1004 on cmbSave_Click button", along with help transferring data from macros to data sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a macro based spreadsheet to transfer inputted data to another sheet labeled "data". Im only getting a runtime error 1004 when I click on the cmbSave_Click() button. I feel the issue is with my line of code being "iRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A40").End.Row + 1", but I am not sure. Im still trying to learn excel VBA.

I have tried debugging the code and also tried commenting code to try to come up with a solution.

```
Private Sub cmbSave_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim iRow As Long

iRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A50").End(x1down).Row + 1

If ValidateForm = True Then

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

   .Range("A" & iRow).Value = iRow - 1
   .Range("B" & iRow).Value = txtName.Value
   .Range("C" & iRow).Value = txtScholar.Value
   .Range("D" & iRow).Value = txtDate.Value
   .Range("E" & iRow).Value = txtSession.Value
   .Range("F" & iRow).Value = cmbReason.Text
   .Range("G" & iRow).Value = txtComments.Value

End With

Call Reset

Else

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

   End If

     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Data should be able to input and save onto the other "data" sheet

Comment: Perhaps give the [`Range.End`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end) documentation a read - you need to specify the direction. Also - `Range("A")`, `Range("B")` and so on are problematic, unless those are named ranges.

Comment: I read the documentation and also changed the code in reference to the documentation, but I am still getting an error. Range "A" & "B" is in reference to the other sheet where I want the destination of the data to end up at. SO "A" and "B" are referring to the columns! I really appreciate the reply though. Do you have any other thoughts? Or maybe possibly any suggestions on changing the code in general.

Comment: You need to add the direction: `.End(xlDown)` for example. For the other issue, you need a row reference: `Range("A" & iRow)`.

Comment: Still having an issue with the data not being transferred over to other "Sheet". I have updated the code up above as follows. Im sure you are right though, I think the destination could be the problem. I will look further into it.

Comment: `xlDown`, not `x1Down`. It's the letter `l`, not the number `1`.

Comment: awesome!! It works, thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome. This is a common confusion, even though `xl` -> `Excel` but many confuse the `l` and `1`. Oh well...